# How to solve the problem of cannot read property addEventListener of null

Tags: javascript, c#, dom, iis, addeventlistener

I am rendering the paypal button in my application and when the page is loading it shows me the error in the console:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at er.error (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaAW2HxBuPPI3Awa__I7KGk8FYCLkia1jgm91t8SlBJAULAA4mHOc8oVBcOBp-MlVfyh24svB2EyPiNs&disable-funding=credit,card:3:60631)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaAW2HxBuPPI3Awa__I7KGk8FYCLkia1jgm91t8SlBJAULAA4mHOc8oVBcOBp-MlVfyh24svB2EyPiNs&disable-funding=credit,card:2:68388)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)....
```

this is the code

```
var initPaypal = function(){
        try
        {
            
            paypal.Buttons({

                style: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    color: 'gold',
                    shape: 'pill',
                    //size: 'responsive',
                    //label: 'pay',
                    //fundingicons : 'false',
                    //tagline: 'true'
                },
                //enableStandardCardFields: false,

                onInit: function(data, actions) {
                    actions.disable();

                    document.querySelector('#invalidCheck')                 
                      .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                          if (gsp.creditCardModel.get("agreePolicy")) {
                              actions.enable();
                          } else {
                              actions.disable();
                          }
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your project work properly locally? Or does this error only appear when published on iis?

```
document.querySelector('#invalidCheck')
```

If it's local, the first thing you need to check is whether `invalidCheck` is null. If it still does not work, the reason for this error may be the script is executed before the page loads, you can try to place the script at the bottom of the page.